# How to insert wicket components into 'sub-rows' of a Wicket DataTable

Tags: java, wicket

I wish to add subrows to my DataTable (as done in [How to insert 'sub-rows' into a Wicket DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822324/how-to-insert-sub-rows-into-a-wicket-datatable)), but I'd like to go a step further and add my own custom wicket components within the added html for the sub-row. Since the extra HTML in that question was added in the onRender it's always too late to add components. Is there another way to add the markup and Wicket components as a sub-row of a DataTable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an `AbstractColumn` instead of a `PropertyColumn`. For example:

```
columns.put(new AbstractColumn<TestResult>(new Model<String>("test column")) {
    @Override
    public void populateItem(Item<ICellPopulator<TestResult>> cellItem, String componentId, IModel<TestResult> rowModel) {
        cellItem.add(new MyComponent(componentId));
    }
});
```

Comment: I actually ended up using wicket fragments for each row, but this seems to work too.

Comment: Could you please describe your solution with fragments? I am facing a similar problem.

Comment: I think this is not valid answer as this inserts another <tr> into data table, resulting in <tr> inside <tr>