# Wicket nesting DataTable

Tags: java, datatable, wicket, nested

Is it possible in Wicket & Java to make DataTable nested in another DataTable.

I have following objects:

```
public class Writer {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<Book> bookList;
     ......
}

public class Book {
    private String title;
    private publicationYear;
       ...
}
```

I need display it in following way:

```
| Show deatil | First name | Last name |
|-------------|------------|-----------|
|      +      |  xxxx      |   yyyy    | 
|      -      |  aaaa      |   bbbbbb  |
|--------------------------------------|  
| Title    | Publication year          |
|----------|---------------------------|
|  Title 1 |  1992                     |
|  Title 2 |  1994                     |
|--------------------------------------|
|      +      |   zzzz     |   oooo    |
|--------------------------------------|
```

Comment: I don't know why it wouldn't be possible. What if you try and then asks for a specific problem?

Comment: I have tried it but I not unableto do it so some hint fit to me

Comment: It would be hard to do in Wicket by using only the DefaultDataTable. Perhaps you can use TreeTable (not exactly what you want). Else you have to write your own.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to write your own extension of DefaultDataTable. See here: [How to insert 'sub-rows' into a Wicket DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822324/how-to-insert-sub-rows-into-a-wicket-datatable?rq=1)
for a good start.

Basically, override `newRowItem` and add a new `DataTable` to the `item`. Should be doable